# Find JSON array has particular value for particular Key in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, loops

I have the following JSON array:

```
[
  { "id": "1", "service": "B" },
  { "id": "2", "service": "A" },
  { "id": "3", "service": "C" }
]
```

I want to check if the JSON array has service "A", if yes then return true.

I am using angular.js. I used `angualr.forEach` loop for it but `break` is not working in angular forEach. Is there any solution with JavaScript `map` function.

So, I want to create a function which has the above JSON array as an argument and returns true if the JSON array has a particular value("A") for a particular Key("service").

Answer (score 2):

Use native JavaScript [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "1",
  "service": "B"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "service": "A"
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "service": "C"
}];

console.log(data.some(function(v) {
  return v.service == 'A';
}))
```

---

For older browser compatibility check [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Polyfill) option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular foreach anyway. Set the flag to stop the loop. Try this.

```
var breakLoop = false;
angular.forEach(arr, function (val) {
   if (val.service == 'A') {
      breakLoop = true;
   }
});
console.log(breakLoop)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
  function myFunction(data,myVal,myKey){
   var flag=false;
   angular.forEach(data,function(obj,k){
        if(obj[myKey]==myVal){
           flag=true;
          }
        });
   return flag;
  }
```